# Change a time position on the video through RTSP

Tags: video-streaming, vlc, rtsp, sdp

I use cvlc, which creates an rtsp server for ".mp4" streaming.

```
cvlc -vvv play.mp4 --rtsp-host=127.0.0.1 --rtsp-port=554 --sout-keep --sout '#rtp{mux=ts,sdp=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8083/test}'
```

Now I can play the .mp4-file like a live stream, without an abilty of changing the time position in VLC player.
Please tell me, where I have to dig to find out the methods of an RTSP-server creation which allow to change the time position?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I read about SDP protocol and it's packetization-mode, but I can't understand if it's the solution or not.

Answer (score 0):

> where I have to dig to find out the methods of an RTSP-server creation which allow to change the time position?

You may find all vlc CLI options at https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/